# Is it possible to disable tensorboard in raytune?

Tags: python, ray, ray-tune

I'm learning how to use `ray.tune` to optimize my models.

Each execution logs results in `tensorboard` by default. I don't have it installed and I'm not using it. But is there a way to disable it, running all the executions without logging?